# How to add padding to table head (thead)

Tags: html, css

**What I'm trying to do**

I'm trying to implement a table header with a border and drop shadow, and have it include padding on the table head.

**What I've tried**

I gave the div that wraps the table a padding of .75em and when I added a drop-shadow and border to the thead, it did not go around the padding (expected). It did produce the effect I was going for, just there is still padding around the thead that I would like to be included with this effect.

Next I tried moving the .75em padding to the thead and tbody, but it is not working as intended. Inspecting says padding has no effect on internal table elements except cells.

Next I tried to wrap the content **inside** the thead in a div and give that a padding of .75em, but that did not work.

Next I tried to wrap the content **outside** the thead in a div and give that a padding of .75em, but that did not work either.

My DOM looks like this

```
<div class='spreadsheet'>
  <table class='data'>
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to achieve:
[image: What I'm trying to do]

Comment: have you given the table a zero padding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure to understand what you want, but is it working for you?

```
.spreadsheet{
  background:lightblue;
  padding:0.75em;
}

table {
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px lightgray;
  border-spacing: 0;
  background:white;
}

th {
  padding: 20px;
}

thead {
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px lightgray;
}

tbody {
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

[image: Result i have]

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary solution I've added blank rows and columns to each side and gave them a height and width respectively of the padding size. This causes problems with hovering and makes things more complicated than they probably need to be.